# Dealing with help vampires in low-activity tags

Tags: discussion, specific-question, help-vampire

A user has been posting a series of related questions over the last couple of weeks. The questions all deal with continuing to figure out how to communicate with a workout session manager, so different parts of his app can share data.

The questions seem to revolve around needing someone to help him generally understand how to accomplish some abstract programming technique, paraphrased as:

- "How do I pass data to a view controller?"
- "How do I call this other class?"
- "How do I access the session manager to update the UI?"

Although he posts specific code, what he really seems to want is for someone to walk him through the solution, instead of looking to existing SO questions and answers, off-site tutorials, sample code, or programming books.

### A single specific example from today

I tried to close [one of today's questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936237/hkworkoutsessionmanager-protocol-methods-not-getting-called) as too broad, since it asked several off-topic questions about how to create singletons:

> I need to create a singleton so I can share WorkoutSessionManager across the extension and successfully update the UI.
>
> I understand the concept of singletons and realize there are many ways to create one, but I am having difficulty with my setup since I require initialization using context and I need to add code to update the WorkoutSessionManager when the context eventually changes.
>
> So how should I build on the instantiation of my singleton? Also what is the convention for the location of singletons? i.e. when should they be created in a separate class file vs writing it in the Manager that already exists?
>
> ```
> static var sharedManager: WorkoutSessionManager?
> // ... solution ...
> ```

He has an idea of how it could be done, but we're apparently expected to provide the entire solution. Unfortunately, the [watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchkit) tag doesn't attract much interest, and someone *did* come to his "aid" *before* the question got closed, helping him in chat.

#### The outcome?

We're left with *a completely unrelated question* from the original post, which went through **11 revisions**, leading to:

- This accepted ["answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38937458/4151918):

  > You never called that function ... Since this is Watch Kit as we discussed above I do not know the best way to do this ... If you need help with doing this ask the now more specific question you have.

  While "You never called that function..." *is* an answer, perhaps it's a bad answer to a bad question! (I down voted the answer and moved on.)
- [this scary comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936237/hkworkoutsessionmanager-protocol-methods-not-getting-called#comment65230908_38937458) to the answer, and [yet another spawned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938916/code-completion-for-sharedmanager-absent-even-after-declaring-an-instance-of-the).

  > Thanks Stephen. Please feel free to follow my questions as **there will be many related to this project.**

### General notes

I've [tried to close other questions before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839015/code-block-that-populates-wkinterfacepicker-object-causing-runtime-error), but [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938916/using-a-singleton-to-settext-on-a-wkinterfacelabel?noredirect=1#comment65234803_38938916) run into difficulties with the user **not recognizing that their specific case really *is* a dupe** of a very common general question.

Other times, they delete a question that doesn't get help, then repost a nearly identical question to get new eyes on it. *On a positive note, I made some progress [suggesting that they offer a bounty on older questions instead of deleting them and reposting the question a second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730420/calling-external-function-using-watchkit-force-touch-menuitem?noredirect=1#comment64837585_38730420), so it's not all bad.*

Apart from down voting, and voting to close, should anything be done to stem recurring related questions from a single user?

- Do we let them keep asking, until someone finally provides the last missing detail concerning his specific programming problem?
- Should I be flagging this user for repeatedly asking how to use their session manager to accomplish what they want to do?

Comment: They've edited their latest question [9 times](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38938916/revisions) already. Someone previously suggested using a delegate, but he's still struggling with how to pass data to the view controller, and getting tripped up with 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while...' in the process.

Comment: ... and they've [once again deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938916/using-a-singleton-to-settext-on-a-wkinterfacelabel) a question which I voted to close as a dupe. If they keep deleting and reposting, I think I'll just flag that for a mod.

Comment: Won't they eventually run into a question ban?

Comment: Only one of their questions has a negative score, and the deleted ones weren't down voted; I don't think they're going to trip an automated ban.

Comment: @ivarni Post bans are for keeping very low quality questions out. These questions don't seem to be low quality at all, however.

Comment: Looking at this user's list of questions and answers, I don't get the impression this is a *bad* SO citizen. Consider the possibility he is genuinely struggling with this particular topic.

Comment: [swift] is a low-activity tag??  No.  The quality of the Q+A in a [tag] is only as good as the community behind it, you can't really do this battle by yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree that [swift] is not low-activity, but if you look at question views for [apple-watch] questions that are also tagged [swift], I think most swift experts see the question title and don't read it, since it's almost always a [watchkit] question instead of a language question.

Comment: @RadLexus I agree that they're genuinely struggling, and they have been for a few weeks. Despite someone else recommending delegation, [their latest question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938916/using-a-singleton-to-settext-on-a-wkinterfacelabel) never assigns or calls a delegate. They need a lot of hand-holding, yet are still are struggling with the very same problem 10 questions later.